# Animated scrolling when not using standard <a href> links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im using div's with a onclick= function.
That in turn exectues a confirm box.
If users press OK. it redirects using: window.location.hash and auto scrolls to a div id.
Auto scroll works fine. But Animated scroll breaks at this point.

Using conventional a href's  works fine with animated scrolling.

Im an amateur and pieced togheter the following code from different sources. I will post the code and hopefully someone has the answer.

Code:

```
function FrontAsNew() {

 if (confirm("No damage allowed") == true) { window.location.hash = "#side"; }
 else { window.location.hash = "#front"; } 

}

<div id="cosmetics_box" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;" onclick="FrontAsNew()">As new</div>

Animated scroll script: 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$('div').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 2000);
return false;
});
```

So in short: Animated scrolling works fine with conventional a href links. But when using divs as links that exectue a function that uses location.hash the animated scrolling breaks.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your click function is pointing to the "a" tag.  If you want to be able to click a div, change the $('a').click(function (){}); to $('div').click(function (){}); although, you should probably narrow down the div that you're clicking either with a class name or id, otherwise your event will trigger when any even is clicked.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the click function to div. But it's not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function FrontAsNew() {

 if (confirm("No damage allowed") == true) { 
   scrollToTopById('side');
 }
 else { 
   scrollToTopById('front');
 } 

}

function scrollToTopById(id) {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully! Ive been trying to solve this for 3 days with google and trying out various scripts. Im a copy paste developer. As i dont have the money to pay someone for my webdevelopment and i dont have the time to actually learn true coding. I know thats frowned upon and thats why i rarely post on forums. But you helped me big time. Thanks a allot!